# namespace either undefined or redefined, why?

Tags: c++

just a very small program to test how to use the namespace. I divide it into 3 files, since in large product, ns.h is the namespace interface and ns.cpp is the implementation. I cannot put all these stuff into one file.

Here is the code:

```
//ns.h
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
namespace my
{
    int a=1;
    int b=0;
    void test();
}
#endif

//ns.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ns.h"

using namespace my;
//my::a=1;
//my::b=0;
void my::test()
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}

//testns.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ns.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout<<my::b<<std::endl;
    my::test();
}
```

If I keep the above code, and compile will get:

```
testns.obj : error LNK2005: "int my::b" (?b@my@@3HA) already defined in ns.obj
testns.obj : error LNK2005: "int my::a" (?a@my@@3HA) already defined in ns.obj
```

If I comment the statement #include "ns.h" I will get undefined error.

```
D:\mfc\testns.cpp(5) : error C2653: 'my' : is not a class or namespace name
D:\mfc\testns.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
D:\mfc\testns.cpp(6) : error C2653: 'my' : is not a class or namespace name
D:\mfc\testns.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'test' : undeclared identifier
```

Kindly help me if you know how to do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers are for declarations, not definitions. That's nothing to do with the namespace problem.

```
//ns.h
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
namespace my
{
    extern int a, b; // declared, not defined thanks to 'extern'.
    void test();
}
#endif

//ns.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ns.h"

int my::a=1; // now we provide the actual definitions.
int my::b=0;
void my::test()
{
    std::cout << my::a << std::endl;
}

//testns.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ns.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << my::b << std::endl;
    my::test();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works this way, but why I have to use the my:: in the cpp file? This will bring a lot of extra work if the package is large. Any comments?

Comment: I just did it that way for example. A `using namespace my;` doesn't help in `ns.cpp` because that just says "try looking up names in `my` if you can't find them here"; it doesn't say "if I define something new, I want it to be part of `my`". But you can instead write e.g. `namespace my { int a = 1; int b = 0; void test() ... }`. In `testns.cpp` of course you can be `using namespace my`, or perhaps `using my::b; using my::test`.

Comment: Thanks Karl, this really make sense. Great answer! The last way is the neat way I am looking for! Since a lot of times, people may write some codes and I do not want to add a lot of prefix to them.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the two variables `a` and `b` in *ns.h* and then the header file is being included in two source files. This violates the [one definition rule](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) as the variables are now defined in both the translation units that are including *ns.h*.

What you need to do is *declare* variables in the header and *define* them in a single source file.

To fix the problem, change *ns.h* to

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H
namespace my
{
    extern int a;
    extern int b;
    void test();
}
#endif
```

In *ns.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ns.h"

using namespace my;

int my::a=1;

int my::b=0;

void my::test()
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not standard practice to *define* variables in a header file; they are re-defined every time you `#include` the header, leading to the linker errors that you are seeing.

If you need to share variables between source files (and there's very few good reasons for this), then you should *declare* them as `extern` in the header file, and then *define* them in one of your source files.

Comment: I tried this before I post the question. It also gives undefined error.

Comment: yeah, I know I shall add my::a, my::b in the cpp file even I have the statement using namespace my; why is that?

Comment: This answer is also correct, but how can I approve two answers at the same time? Thank you!